# How to get ResponseEntity body in spring-integration

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am using xml based configuration - http outbound gateway to trii=gger a rest service, the response is ResponseEntity and I dont know that service details. The output I receive should be put in a JMS Queue.

How can I update the below to extract only the body of response entity and pass to output-channel? If there is a transformer, please give example. Is it possible using config?

```
<int:chain input-channel="gsInChannel" output-channel="dest-channel">
<int-http:outbound-gateway          
               url="https://ia-zatie.str13.tst.belst.nu/ia-zaatie/rest/signal/v2"
               http-method="POST"  
               header-mapper="headerMapper"
               request-factory="sslFactory"                
               >
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
    </int:chain>
```

dest-channel is jms:outbound-channel-adapter

boot version 1.4.3 and integration version 4.3.6

> Error: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error
>   occurred in message handler
>   [org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler#0];
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException:
>   Cannot convert object of type
>   [org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] to JMS message. Supported
>   message payloads are: String, byte array, Map, Serializable
>   object.

Comment: Added expected-response-type="java.lang.String"

Comment: Sounds like you have found a solution for your problem. You can answer that way and accept your own answer or close the question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using HTTP POST method and so not expecting, a response. SoO has not included expected-response-type, which returns the body

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway          
               url="https://ia-zatie.str13.tst.belst.nu/ia-zaatie/rest/signal/v2"
               http-method="POST"  
               header-mapper="headerMapper"
               request-factory="sslFactory"  

               expected-response-type="java.lang.String">
```